# using ActiveRecord argument in custom generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, migration, generator

i wanna this custom generator named form , generate a model and create its migration file in **db/migrate**

this is output :

```
rails g form test name:string
      create  app/models/name:string.rb
      create  app/controllers/name:strings_controller.rb
      create  app/javascript/api/name:string.js
      create  app/javascript/component/name:strings.vue
      create  app/javascript/pages/name:string/index.vue
      create  app/javascript/pages/name:string/layout.vue
      create  app/javascript/store/actions/name:string.js
      create  app/javascript/store/getters/name:string.js
      create  app/javascript/store/modules/name:string.js
      create  app/javascript/store/mutations/name:string.js
      create  db/migrate/20200816162324_create_name:strings.rb
```

and this is my custom generator class :

```
    require 'rails/generators/active_record'
    class FormGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::Base
      source_root File.expand_path('templates', __FILE__)
      source_root File.expand_path('templates', __dir__)
      argument :model, type: :string

def create_template

    template "models/form.template", "app/models/#{model}.rb"
    template "controllers/forms_controller.template", "app/controllers/#{model}s_controller.rb"
    template "javascript/api/form.template", "app/javascript/api/#{model}.js"
    template "javascript/pages/component/forms.template", "app/javascript/component/#{model}s.vue"
    template "javascript/pages/form/index.template", "app/javascript/pages/#{model}/index.vue"
    template "javascript/pages/form/layout.template", "app/javascript/pages/#{model}/layout.vue"
    template "javascript/store/actions/form.template", "app/javascript/store/actions/#{model}.js"
    template "javascript/store/getters/form.template", "app/javascript/store/getters/#{model}.js"
    template "javascript/store/modules/form.template", "app/javascript/store/modules/#{model}.js"
    template "javascript/store/mutations/form.template", "app/javascript/store/mutations/#{model}.js"
    migration_template "create_forms.template", "db/migrate/create_#{model}s.rb"

    
  end
```

as you can see generator uses the column that i gave it to model instead of model itself

```
template "models/form.template", "app/models/#{model}.rb"   //code
rails g form test name:string
          create  app/models/name:string.rb    //output
```

what should i do to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Ruby on Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#adding-command-line-arguments), if you want to add custom command line arguments to a custom generator you have to declare it as a `class_option`. In this case your custom arguments are an array of columns. For example:

```
class FormGenerator < ActiveRecord::Generators::Base
  ...
  class_option :columns, type: :array, default: [] # Options :type and :default are not required
  
  def create_template
    @columns = options[:columns] # You can use this variable inside template
    ...
  end
end
```

For more information about `class_option` method [click here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/erikhuda/thor/master/Thor/Base/ClassMethods#class_option-instance_method).